# How to add a progressbar and status to a process that doesnt have a count like copying files does?

Tags: c#, multithreading, progress-bar, closedxml

So i had posted a question on getting my sample project working and it now works.. [Sample Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60980973/why-isnt-my-progress-bar-reflecting-the-status)
And thats great because as in that example i have a production project that requires copying files, so that will work great for that one.

But this question is about displaying a progress bar to a process that im not clear on how to implement.

Im reading a excel file using closedxml, i read that file into a datatable in order to perform some filtering and other things in order to populate some listboxes on my form, how can my sample code in my other post be implemented against the creation of 5 or 6 data tables?

I can provide some of the datatable creation methods, but the over all code is close to 600 lines right now and not finished yet.. so below is a stripped down sample of the current code im working with..

```
    private void sample()
    {
        string plink = @"C:\Test\Sizes.xlsx";
        string[] DistinctDept = { "Dept Code", "Dept Description" };

        DataTable ListDept = GetDistinctRecords(LoadExceltoDatatable(plink), DistinctDept);
        ListDept.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DeptCombo", typeof(string), "'('+[Dept Code] +') ' + [Dept Description]"));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ListDept.Rows[0]["Dept Code"].ToString()))
        {
            ListDept.Rows[0].Delete();
            ListDept.AcceptChanges();
        }
        lbDept.DataSource = ListDept;
        lbDept.DisplayMember = "DeptCombo";
        lbDept.ClearSelected();
    }

    public static DataTable GetDistinctRecords(DataTable dt, string[] Columns)
    {
        DataTable dtUniqRecords = new DataTable();
        dtUniqRecords = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, Columns);
        return dtUniqRecords;
    }

    public static DataTable LoadExceltoDatatable(string sizeoptcalc)
    {
        using (var wb = new XLWorkbook(sizeoptcalc, XLEventTracking.Disabled))
        {
            var ws = wb.Worksheet(1);
            var foundMonth = ws.Search("Month", System.Globalization.CompareOptions.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            var monthRow = foundMonth.Last().Address;  // A11
            var lastcell = ws.LastCellUsed().Address; // BC3950
            DataTable dataTable = ws.Range(monthRow, lastcell).RangeUsed().AsTable().AsNativeDataTable();
            return dataTable;
        }
    }
```

Can this be changed to report the progress? I mean in some cases the excel files are large and do take some time to fill in my listboxes.

Here are more of the datatable creations that i would like to account for the overall progress of them

[image: More samples of the logic im trying to report progress on]

Comment: For which line of code do you want to add a progress bar?

Comment: you are correct, there is no copy, thats the reason for my question. This operation just takes a long period of time to complete, based on the size of the excel file.. the line that takes the longest is this line DataTable ListDept = GetDistinctRecords, because its reading in the file, then parsing out the data needed per column filter and then each data table created is displayed in a listbox.  Keep in mind that there are a total of 8 datatables im creating, the above is merely a small snippet of all the code that i run in order to populate each listbox.

Comment: the more i looked around today, the more i think that in my case, i just need to display a animated image at the beginning of the logic and close that when the process is over.. dont think we need to worry about number of rows or records, just that its being worked on.